# PHP - Change only one row, not all

Tags: php

I've just started with PHP and literally been stuck now for 5 hours straight trying to figure this out! I understand what's happening but cannot for the life of me find a fix anywhere D: Basically each row is displayed on the users browser. Beside each one is a 'Mark as complete' button. When this button is pressed is changes the value from 0 to 1. Problem is, it changes the value of 0 to 1 for every row D: Please help me it's a pain in the but now haha! Heres my code:

```
<?php

// Declare Variables
$host = localhost;
$user = root;
$pass = root;
$db = test;

// Create connection to database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// Check to see if connection was established
if($link === false) {
die("Connection could not be established to database" .mysqli_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE Status = 0";

// Show data
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>First name</th>";
echo "<th>Last name</th>";
echo "<th>Destination</th>";
echo "<th>Value</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<form action='complete.php' method='post'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Destination'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' value='Mark as complete'>" . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} 
else{
echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
} 
else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

?>
```

and complete.php

```
<?php

// Declare Variables
$host = localhost;
$user = root;
$pass = root;
$db = test;

// Create connection to database
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

// Check to see if connection was established
if($link === false) {
die("Connection could not be established to database" .mysqli_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "UPDATE details SET Status=1";

if ($link == true) {
echo "Marked as complete";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
}

mysqli_close($link)
?>
```

Comment: There is no code here that updates the database

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE details SET Status=1";` no `WHERE` clause. *Tah-dah!!*

Comment: I just added the complete.php - Sorry about that

Comment: So a where clause - Is this where were talking about an ID assigned to that row?

Comment: *Smart cookie* ^ ;-)

Comment: I tried this earlier but I could only add one row. It would not allow me to add any more

Comment: Well one problem is...You forgot to close your form! ;)

Comment: Your problem to my mind seems to be that you don't know enough SQL.  Go install an SQL based database and learn to write the queries you need by hand, apart from the PHP.  Once you have a solid grasp on what you're doing, then think about how you need to add this to your PHP project.  And remember little Bobby Tables;  (https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You might try SQLFiddle to experiment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Cheers guys I'll have a look at the resources!

Comment: Please, close the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You are missing some steps. Here is the full process as you want to do.
Just replace with your. I hope this will solve your problem.

<?php

    // Declare Variables
    $host = localhost;
    $user = root;
    $pass = root;
    $db = test;

    // Create connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    // Check to see if connection was established
    if($link === false) {
    die("Connection could not be established to database" .mysqli_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE Status = 0";

    // Show data
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>First name</th>";
    echo "<th>Last name</th>";
    echo "<th>Destination</th>";
    echo "<th>Value</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form action='complete.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Destination'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' value='Mark as complete'>" . "</td>";
    // Put your primary key column name in the place of Id
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='".$row['Id']."'>"; 
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    } 
    else{
    echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
    } 
    else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    ?>

and complete.php


<?php

    // Declare Variables
    $host = localhost;
    $user = root;
    $pass = root;
    $db = test;

    // Create connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    // Check to see if connection was established
    if($link === false) {
    die("Connection could not be established to database" .mysqli_error());
    }

    // sql to delete a record
    // Put your primary key column name in the place of Id
    $sql = "UPDATE details SET Status=1 WHERE Id='".$_POST['user_id']."' "; 

    if ($link == true) {
    echo "Marked as complete";
    } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $link->error;
    }

    mysqli_close($link)
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you amit, but it won't let me add more than one record to my table :/  It just comes up with .mysql_error(INSERT INTO system_data (ID, FirstName, LastName, Destination, Occupation, Status) VALUES ('', ','','us','', ''))

Comment: The name of the table has changed by the way :) Updated all the values for it. I was having this problem last night too. It only happens when I add the ID field to the database. Without it, it works fine

Comment: Jackthomson, there is no need to add ID field during the inserting the records in the table. Just make the ID field as a integer primary key with AUTO_INCREMENT. Then the ID field value will be automatically insert for each row. Use like this (INSERT INTO system_data (FirstName, LastName, Destination, Occupation, Status) VALUES ('', '','us','', ''))

Comment: I understand. I have removed that but it still will not add more than one row. Bloody confused now haha!

Comment: Can you send me the insert script code and your database table's structure that you are using?

Comment: Of course. Here's a link to the dropbox folder and I've taken a screenshot of the structure - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mhobskkgx8eeyi9/AADWNBLFE2zdcmS8eEzJMhIha?dl=0 Thank you

Comment: just get the backup of your database "details" table and then delete it. And then create a new fresh table by using the below query.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `details` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` text NOT NULL,
  `LastName` text NOT NULL,
  `Destination` text NOT NULL,
  `Occupation` text NOT NULL,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: And then check more than one record is inserting or not in the table

Comment: I literally just figured it out haha! I didn't select the Auto Increment field so I can see why now how it wasn't working! Thank you! Just a quick question when I press the button mark as complete it doesn't actually assign the value 1 :/?

Comment: Explain in detail, where the value is not assigning. Or send screen-shot.

Comment: So on the get.php page you click the button mark as complete. This then goes to complete.php. It says it worked but when you go back to get.php and refresh the page the default value of 0 is still there. It doesn't actually update :s The complete.php file was pasted at the start of this thread. It did work at first but now the value of 1 that I have stated in complete.php is not being assigned :(

Comment: In your "complete.php", the update query is not executing. Just add the below line:

Comment: mysqli_query($link, $sql);

Comment: after this line $sql = "UPDATE details SET Value = 1 WHERE ID ='".$_POST['id']."' ";

Comment: Thank you so much Amit for all your help! Your a legend!